# Refresh parent window from child with multiple parent window using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tree window (first-> second -> third). I want to reload second by closing third one. But after closing third one the first one getting refresh. I had written following script.

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
self.close(); 
function refreshParent() {
     window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: It's not detail to make any assessment :) Please indicate more clearly

Comment: first page opening one pop-up and on that pop-up there is one more pop up window. on last one pop up window , if I close it and trying to refresh opened pop up, that time it refreshing the page not the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this script in third window's html file and see if it works. Also, make sure you give an unique name for all the windows.

```
<script>
    window.onunload = closeMeAndRefreshOpener;
    function closeMeAndRefreshOpener() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        self.close();
    }
</script>
```